# How to get clustered standard errors in R? Misceadds package doesn't install

Tags: r, robust

I am trying to install the package Miceadds to estimate clustered standard errors but it doesn't install on my computer. I am using mac. Instead, now I am trying the coeftest function from one of the packages installed.

The coeftest function, however, doesn't give the correct result for the probit regression I have run earlier since the errors don't change no matter which cluster I use.

```
install.packages("sandwich")
install.packages("plm")
install.packages("lmtest")
library(sandwich)
library(plm)
library(lmtest)
coeftest(probitreg1, vcov.=vcovHC(probitreg, cluster= c("state", "year")))
coeftest(probitreg1, vcov.=vcovHC(probitreg, cluster= "year"))
```

The clustered standard errors are coming out to be smaller than I expected even though ideally, they should be larger since intra-state variation in voting will lead to underestimated standard errors. Am I using the coeftest correctly?

Comment: You might be looking for the [`vcovCL()` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sandwich/versions/2.5-1/topics/vcovCL) in sandwich.

Comment: I've used this as vcovCL(probitreg1, cluster=AEH_replication$state, sandwich=TRUE)
 Can you elaborate on how to interpret the vcovCL result? It doesn't give me any estimates of standard errors?